# working with asp.net default profile provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, profile, membership

I have searched everywhere for this and it seems like there isn't any obvious solution.
I have a website with a lot of users but I need to store a globally unique profile value (phone) nobody can use the same phone number twice.

It would be very slow to loop through all my users get their phone values and match them against the user provided one to reject it.

Is there a way to make a profile value unique to all users? Just like a username is unique or a email? Thanks.

Comment: where are you storing the users (SQL)?  where are you searching for the users if you were to search for the phone number that way?  Why not index the phone numbers so it's very easy to look it up?  If the users are in a collection in C#, then you could use a different collection type.  If in SQL, add an index to your table for the phone field.

Comment: I'm using asp.net default membership/profile provider.

Comment: Doesn't that methodology check the web.config for configuration only, and stores the user's application information (user id, etc..) within the secure session cookie?  What I'm asking is where are you storing your data for all these users (for example, when you create/update/delete/retrieve users)?  Are you storing them in Active Directory, SQL?  Your query on this data will have to look at some index to avoid the duplicate phone number--when you create or update a user.

Comment: everything is stored on mssql 2008 r2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you create an index in a table in SQL:

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_CUSTOMER_PHONE on user (phone)
```

When you query the database, it'll look up your value by quickly searching the table for the phone number, rather than looping through all values:

```
SELECT phone FROM user WHERE phone = '555-555-5555'
```

If you need help with the implementation in your C# code, it will require you to query the database.  My suggestion would be to write your stored procedure such that it returns 2 result sets.  The first result set would be the record itself and the second result set would return true or false whether it errored out during the save (on create or update).  In your C# code, check the errors result set first, and display duplicate if it returned a result set.

Comment: my main issue here is sql. I'm really bad at it and i'm not sure how tables are created... :/

Comment: email me at wcfguy at yahoo dot com and i can help answer any questions tomorrow.. if you haven't configured sql server, you may run into a lot along the way ... start by creating your table in SQL Server Management Studio in object explorer .. and let me know how far you get